# React.Addons.CreateFragment issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We recently did an upgrade of React to 0.13, and this little warning starts popping up:

Warning: Any use of a keyed object should be wrapped in React.addons.createFragment(object) before being passed as a child.

Here is my code, tried to figure out how to use the createFragment, but couldnt really find any good examples on how to do it when wrapping elements from this.props.children.

This.props.children will in my case be other React components that should be wrapped in an li. Have any of you seen or solved this issue before?

```
import React from 'react';

module.exports = React.createClass({
  displayName: "public/src/scripts/components/info-block/infoItem.js",
  propTypes: {
    label: React.PropTypes.string,
    children: React.PropTypes.any
  },
  renderChildren: function(){
    var elementsToRender = [].concat(this.props.children);

    return elementsToRender.map(function(elem, i){
      return <li key={i}>{elem}</li>
    });
  },
  render : function(){
    return (
      <li>
        <span className="ll">{this.props.label}</span>
        <span className="lr">
          <ul>
            {this.renderChildren()}
          </ul>
        </span>
      </li>
    );
  }
});
```

I tried switching the renderChildren method to this:

```
renderChildren: function(){
  return React.Children.map(this.props.children, function(elem){
    return React.addons.createFragment({value: <li>{elem}</li>});
  });
}
```

It will render then, but i still get the warning

Comment: is `{elem}` a plain string? I got same error when  trying to render a javascript object without a JSON.stringify(obj) applied to it.

Comment: Ive had it happening both on strings and when this.props.children contains other react components